# Is it possible to turn on existing file into terraform resource

Tags: terraform

I wonder there is an option in terraform to reference the file without specifying the content. The Problem is that I have a file, to be more exactly I Installed it via helm,
and it is over 4000 lines, (cert-manager for managing ssl internally and externally in the cluster) and I don't really want to rewrite the whole configuration into terraform manifest syntax, so just do something like that...

```
resource "<some-resource>" "<some-name>" {
   
   link = "<my cert-manager file.yaml>"
```

Is this Scenario possible in the Terraform world?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [file](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file) function, that you can use to read a file.

```
> file("${path.module}/hello.txt")
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I find approximate solution for that, so if you have a large yaml file (for example) and you want to apply it directly to your cluster or whatever compute instance you can do something like that, using `terraform provisioner`

```
resource "null_resource" "apply-file-configuration-to-server" {

     provisioner "local-exec" { // means that the command will be executed on local machine, that you are running terraform on...

          command = "<whatever-command-to-apply-configuration-file (for example in Kubernetes, "kubectl apply -f file.yaml") "

     }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but this answers a different question than how to load a file in terraform. Using a local provisioner is fine, but it has its own issues. Even [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) suggest using them as a last resort. Maybe you would get some benefit out of using the [helm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs).